# prompting the user until they give a number not a string and one that is bigger than the previous number entered

Tags: python-3.6

I'm making a program where the user needs to input 2 numbers(negative or positive) and the second one has to be bigger than the first one by at least 2. Is there a way to make sure the user inputs that. I already have it so it only excepts a number but is there a way to do both at once. Here's my code:

```
while True:
    try:
        lowest_num = int(input("What would you like the lowest possible number to be?"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please only enter a number.  Try again... ")

while True:
    try:
        highest_num = int(input("What would you like the highest possible number to be?"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please only enter a number and a number that is bigger than the previous number.  Try again...")
```

I need something like this to be in the same loop as the "highest_num loop":

```
while highest_num <= (lowest_num + 1):
    highest_num = input("Please only enter a number and a number that is bigger than the previous number.")
```

is there a way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should seek to combine both `while` loops. Also your `while` clause could actually check the difference between highest_num and lowest_num

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I put a new `while` loop inside the `try`, like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        highest_num = int(input("What would you like the highest possible number to be?"))
        while highest_num <= (lowest_num + 1):
            highest_num = int(input("Please only enter a number and a number that is bigger than the previous number."))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please only enter a number and a number that is bigger than the previous number.  Try again...")
```

and I'm pretty sure that worked!